# InteropServices.COMException in ExportAsFixedFormat but only in Windows 10

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I'm developing a winform that maps XML data to an Excel template file. The XML map is set in the Excel template.

Then, I export the Excel to PDF:

```
Application xApp = new Application();
Workbook excelWorkBook = xApp.Workbooks.Open(@"" + ExcelTMPLPath, Type.Missing, false);   
excelWorkBook.XmlMaps["NewDataSet_Map"].Import(TransXMLFilePath);

excelWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, PDFOUTPUTFilePath, XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true);

excelWorkBook.Close();
xApp.Workbooks.Close();
```

This is working on multiple Windows 7 machines, with both Excel 2013 and 2016.

But on two Windows 10 laptops, it's giving the following error during the ExportAsFixedFormat call:

"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010105): The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))"

I'm confused because it's mentioning a server but this is all run locally on the machine. Even more confused because it was working on the Windows 10 machines up until a couple of weeks ago.

However, if I use an Excel file with no XML mapping at all, it works and exports it to PDF, so it seems like an issue with the XML mapping. But it's strange that this wouldn't work in Windows 10.

Does anyone have a clue as to what could be the issue, and what might be a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: COM uses a client-server model where a client (your application) connects to a server (Excel) which it sends requests to and gets replies from via messaging.  The critical thing we need to know is what line of your code throws the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The ExportAsFixedFormat call is throwing the exception (the 4th line).

Comment: then I have bad news.  While I have no personal experience here with this bug and I find the answer fishy, the VB.net link I provided above may be your answer or at least a workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the solution there and see if it works.